# border-box with padding can't have 0 width

Tags: css, border-box

Consider this code

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  width: 0;
  height: 0;    
  max-width: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>Hi</div>
```

According to everything I've ever [read, understood, and used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) about `box-sizing: border-box;` This should show nothing since the width and height are zero and padding/border are inside of the zero width and height.

What we see however is a 26x26 box ((12 padding + 1 border)*2). What gives? Why is `border-box` not working here?

Comment: What you want is physically impossible. The browser has to make a choice: either honour the padding, or the width. If it would show 0 pixels, people would start complaining that it didn't honour the padding.

Comment: @MrLister That's the definition of `box-sizing: border-box`, isn't it? That width includes padding and border

Comment: @MrLister: I don't think this represents "an impossible goal" so much as it represents a (potential) bug/ambiguity in the spec versus expectation.

Comment: @MrLister Correct, however I would assume that the browsers internal rendering logic has some conditional that will render this a certain way based on whether or not is has content.  Hope you get a detailed answer.

Comment: Yeah, seriously @DavidThomas that could certainly be considered a bug in the spec

Comment: it is not a bug to me , if padding is included into calculation, how do you  include / remove it from 0. spec doesn't say it erases it

Comment: @GCyrillus yeah, but it seems like the spec is specifying implementation details, which is simply not what specs should do.

Comment: if padding should not be applied, why border width should if box is set to 0 height/width and box-sizing to border-box ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does box-sizing: border-box still show the border with a width of 0px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142330/why-does-box-sizing-border-box-still-show-the-border-with-a-width-of-0px)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css3-ui-20150224/#box-sizing),

> The content width and height are calculated by subtracting the border
>   and padding widths of the respective sides from the specified [width](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visudet.html#propdef-width)
>   and [height](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visudet.html#propdef-height) properties. As the content width and height [cannot be
>   negative](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property) ([CSS21], section 10.2), this computation is floored at 0.

Therefore, your element effectively has a height and a width of 0. But you see it bigger because of the padding and the border.

Comment: That doesn't really explain what's going on here. Should the height and width be zero then?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Again, what you are trying to do is physically impossible.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I think the important part here is where it says "**The content width**".  So the content width is 0, but the padding and border are still applied on top of that.

Comment: Oooooh, I see what you're getting at. Well hell...how do you do a zero-sized container with a padding that expands to a width then? Do we *still* have to hack around things with intermediate elements?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer An outer wrapper that's 0 and an inner element with the padding?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer You use box-sizing:content-box.

Comment: @MrLister nah, `content-box` has the same effect.

Comment: I still don't know what you want. A zero content plus a positive padding is still a positive amount of space. If you want a total width of zero, use zero padding! So please explain what you do want.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer If you don't want the padding, remove it. Tricks with `width` and `box-sizing` won't work.

Comment: @MrLister I'm pretty sure the intent is to have the text in the element padded, but if the element gets smaller than the padding for it to clip the padding and still resize down as far as 0.

Comment: @MrLister Yeah, the actual use case for me is a padded container that is not rendered due to having a zero width, but when the parent is hovered-over it slides out to its natural width. I can do it a dozen ways, but I was excited since this seems to not be hacky at all, except then...this. In other words, what I expect, is when I set `border-box` and specify `width: 0`, for the element not to render at all except for any margin

Comment: @GeorgeMauer If you don't want it rendered, why don't you just use `display:none`.

Comment: @MrLister absolutely, and that's probably what I will do, but then I have to put `display: flex` on the selector that causes it to slide out which is mildly hacky.

Comment: Actually @MrLister that won't work. Check out [this](http://jsbin.com/foxefuwobo/2/edit?html,css,output) versus [this](http://jsbin.com/foxefuwobo/1/edit?html,css,output). Notice that the latter doesn't animate expansion (and also forces you to put `display: flex` on *all* expandables). Sounds like the best solution is to use a hacky intermediate element.